# Google ReCaptcha v3 error for site owner: invalid site key?

Tags: node.js, recaptcha

Hello I am trying to use recaptchav3 and running index.html on nodejs server hosted on localhost and I added localhost to domain the recaptcha setting

This is how the backend route looks like

```
    app.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.captcha === undefined || req.body.captcha === '' || req.body.captcha === null) {
    return res.json({"success": false, "message": "Please select Captcha"})
  }

  // Secret key
  const secretKey = '';

  const verifyUrl = `https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${req.body.captcha}`;

  // Make Request to Verify Url
  request(verifyUrl, (err, response, body) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);

    if (body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
      return res.json({"success": false, "message": "Failed Captcha verification"})
    }

    return res.json({"success": true, "msg": "Captcha passed"})
  })

})
```

and how the frontend looks like

```
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render="></script>

            <div class="form-group">
          <div class="g-recaptcha"
          data-sitekey=""
          data-callback='onSubmit'
          data-action='submit'></div>
        </div>

    function submitForm(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("clicked");
            grecaptcha.ready(function() {
              grecaptcha.execute('', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
                  // Add your logic to submit to your backend server here.
              });
            });
```

Why am I getting error that invalid site key?

Comment: You need to add site key to data-sitekey.  If you omitted it from your question for security reasons that’s completely unnecessary and not a security risk (or just leave nonempty in future and let us know it’s correctly added)

Comment: I added it and only removed it for security risk here i dont wanna share keys